# Sorting DataGrid values with button press

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am making a download manager, And I am having trouble updating the values for the progress bar column, I am trying to make it so that when I press the "downloading" button only the progress bars with values below 100% will be shown in the the DataGird

[Program image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYv5Y.jpg)

**Xaml DataGrid code**

```
            <!--List of the programs currently used/downloaded-->
            <DataGrid x:Name="DG_List" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      IsReadOnly="true" ColumnWidth="*">

                <DataGrid.Columns>

                    <!--#region Program Number -->
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="ProgramID" 
                                            Header="#">

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <!--#region Adds a dot at the end of a number-->
                                <TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock.Text>
                                        <Binding Path="ProgramID">
                                            <Binding.StringFormat>

                                                {0}.

                                            </Binding.StringFormat>
                                        </Binding>
                                    </TextBlock.Text>
                                </TextBlock>
                                <!--#endregion-->

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <!--#endregion-->


                    <!--#region Program Number -->
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="Name" 
                                            Header="Name">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <!--#endregion-->


                    <!--#region Program Number -->
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="Size" 
                                            Header="Size">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Size}"/>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <!--#endregion-->


                    <!--#region Progress bar columns -->
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="Progress" 
                                            Header="Progress">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                            <DataTemplate>

                                <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress}" />

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <!--#endregion-->


                    <!--#region Progress bar columns -->
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="Bandwidth" 
                                            Header="Bandwidth">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding BandWidth}" />

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <!--#endregion-->

                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
```

**Code behind for the event**

```
        private void Btn_Downloading_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Programs P = new Programs();

            //Loops through every "Program" in the program list
            for (int a = 0; a < P.ProgramList().Count; a++)
            {

                if (P.Progress <= 100)
                {

                    *Here is where the event/Sort supposed to happen*

                }

            }
        }
```

If anything is missing tell me I will gladly add it

Edit:
**New code**

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        Programs P = new Programs();

        private bool _showOnlyNotFinishedDownloads = false;


        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            //Sets the item source to the list of programs
            //DG_List.ItemsSource = P.ProgramList();

            P.ProgramsView = new CollectionViewSource { Source = P }.View; P.ProgramsView.Filter = FilterPrograms;

        }
```

but now `P.ProgramsView = new CollectionViewSource { Source = P }.View; P.ProgramsView.Filter = FilterPrograms;` throws an exception saying

" 'DownloadManager_v2._5_1.Downloads.Programs' is not a valid value for property 'Source'.' "

Comment: Hello again, have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using `ICollectionFilter` for this.

This could look like this

Add a `ICollectionView` instance in your viewmodel like this

```
public ICollectionView ProgramsView { get; set; }
```

and a property like this

```
private bool _showOnlyNotFinishedDownloads = false;
```

After you defined the collection with is the `ItemsSource` of your `DataGrid` define the `ICollectionView` like this (assuming `Programs` is the name of the collection.

ProgramsView = new CollectionViewSource{ Source = Programs }.View;
            ProgramsView.Filter = FilterPrograms;

Add the filter method like this (this method will return `true` when the `Program` should be shown and `false` when not.

```
private bool FilterPrograms(object programObject)
{
    if(_showOnlyNotFinishedDownloads)
    {
        Programs program = programObject as Programs;
        bool showProgram = program.Progress < 100;
        return showProgram;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When you press the downloading button add this to the method which will be called

```
_showOnlyNotFinishedDownloads = true;
ProgramsView.Refresh();
```

And change the `ItemsSource` of your `DataGrid` to this

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ProgramsView}"...
```

When you want to show all programs you have to set `showOnlyNotFinishedDownloads = false` and call `ProgramsView.Refresh();`.

Comment: I didn't really understand what you meant by defining the with the ItemsSource of my DataGrid can you expand on it please ?

Comment: You have bound the `ItemsSource` of your `DataGrid` as far as I know from your last question. Or in which way do you populate your `DataGrid`?

Comment: Yeah I did I bound it to a method through the C# code not the xaml

Comment: I've added the `FilterPrograms` method but it says `_showOnlyNotFinishedDownloads` does not exits in the current context

Comment: You have to add the field as well.

Comment: I added the filed in the same class that i added the `ProgramsView ` property

Comment: Should I send you an image of the code will it make it easier to understand ?

Comment: You could edit your answer. But don't post code as an image

Comment: Thank you it took a while(A long while at that) but I'v finally managed to understand your answer I cant ever thank you enough